# How to convert or replicate Mystic Mountains brushes from Corel Essentials 6 to Corel Painter 2019

Tags: brush, corel-painter

Last year, I asked [Is there a good free replacement for the "Foliage" brush in Corel's Bob Ross "Mystic Mountain" toolset?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/106774/), about doing the provided Mystic Mountains tutorial despite not having the full brush set. I eventually just settled for improvising without all of the provided brushes. I have since bought another Humble Bundle, this one including Corel Painter 2019. And so I decided to try to use those Essentials brushes I'd received before in Painter 2019. Unfortunately, the installer provided would not install to Painter, and I cannot find the brush files to import. And, even if I wanted to buy those brushes anew, their license expired, so the Bob Ross brushes are no longer available for purchase.

How do I export these brushes from Essentials 6 in a format that Corel Painter 2019 will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I don't have a good answer here, but I can provide what I have learned. It is possible to export two of the brushes, "2 inch blender" and "2 inch landscape brush" by right-clicking the Mystic Mountains Essentials category and selecting "?ExportCategory?" (I'm guessing the question marks aren't supposed to be there, but they are), which exports a ".brushcategory" file. It is also possible to export the aforementioned "2 inch" brushes via right-clicking on them, which provides ".brushvariant" files. These files can be imported in Corel Painter 2019 via the `Brushes / Import` menu option. Unfortunately, the other brushes do not export.

Since I was unable to find any solutions online, or on my own, I contacted Corel technical support. After a few abortive attempts to explain that I had received the brush pack via a bundle download rather than from the store, which meant I couldn't just redownload it from the store, they first sent me a ".pkg" file (which seems to be a zip archive, but is apparently a Macintosh install file), which they had no idea how to import, and then the actual installation package, which basically runs as an executable.

So, long story short, as best I can tell, there is not a good export/import path between the two programs, but there is a side channel by which tech support can just send you the brush package in question (which you will want to store away because it will not appear among your store purchases).

As another note for those who missed their chance at the Mystic Mountains brushes, there's a very similar set of brushes in the Udemy course, [Corel Painter 2018 Brush Set and Brush Tutorials](https://www.udemy.com/share/102hKMBkUYeV1XQHg=/), complete with explanations of how to use them and how to adjust their settings, and the creator of those brushes, Karen Bonaker, [has them for sale on her site](https://www.digitalartacademy.com/product-page/mystic-mountain-complete-brush-pack).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do a similar thing, converting all of my ultimate essentials bundle into Painter 2019. The only way I could figure out how to do it is to just export all of the brushed individually from each pack, Or in your case just the one, and import them into painter 2019 using the import feature in the brushes menu. To export the brushes from Painter essentials, right click on the brush and click "?Export?" (or something similar. Don't Use export brush category as it only exported a single brush (for me personally).